# Python - can't import another module

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I have a module A.py without any functions.  It's code that imports a number of CSV files, reads them, and outputs another CSV file.

I have another module B.py in the same project directory, which is only functions, which are used by its main function `create_output` to generate a string.  Neither file has any classes.

I'm trying to run `B.create_output` to generate the string inside A.py, and write it into the CSV file.  However, I can't import B into A.

```
from B import *
# run create_output
```

gets `NameError: global name 'create_output' is not defined`

```
from B import create_output
# run create_output
```

gets `ImportError: cannot import name create_output`

```
import B
# run B.create_output
```

gets `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'create_output'`

Do I have to create a class in B in order to import it?  Why can't I reference B inside A?  I could put all B functions into A, but I prefer to keep A clean, since B has a lot of stuff going on and it's a very specific process.

Comment: You may not be importing what you think you're importing.  Does anything else have the same name as `B`?  What does `import B; print(dir(B))` show you?

Comment: Oh my god you're right... B.py actual name is "parser.py" and I didn't realize that was a built-in... Thank you!  So amateur.